# Pass a reference to a DOM element into React

Tags: reactjs, dom, jsx

I have a reference to a DOM element (from a 3rd-party library) and need to render it it React. I can think of a couple ways do this, but I'm hoping to find a solution that's more straightforward and doesn't require converting the element to a string first. For example:

```
const el = document.createElement('div');
el.textContent = 'test';

// This works but requires converting the element to a string first.
const reactEl = (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: el.innerHTML}} />
);

// Something like this should also work, but it seems overly complicated.
function MyComponent() {
  const myRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current.appendChild(el);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={myRef} />
  );
}
```

Is there another, more straightforward way to insert a DOM element into jsx?

Comment: If you're not populating with innerHTML, `appendChild` seems like the right solution here. You could probably extract the code into a convenience hook, if there's not already an open source one that does this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your second method is the correct way to do it in React. It may seem complicated, but it's not.

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const myRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current.appendChild(el);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={myRef} />
  );
}
```